# How to cleanup ‘orphaned’ text in poorly written html using Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Let me explain: I scrapped html off a poorly written website and wish to clean up the code by encapsulating each line within a `<div>` tag, keep the existing `bold`, `italic` and other formatting information, keep the `images` and `links`. I will then format everything and prettify it once cleaned.

Below are 3 sample lines from the website:

```
line1 = '1. O: upper border of 1st rib &amp; cartilage.<div>2. I: inferior surface of middle third of the clavicle.&nbsp;</div><div>3. NS: nerve to subclavius.&nbsp;</div><div>4. A: anchors &amp; depresses clavicle.&nbsp;</div><div><br></div><div><div><img src="paste-3461743641109.jpg"></div><div><span style="font-weight: bolder">Image:&nbsp;</span>Gray, Henry.&nbsp;<i>Anatomy of the Human Body.</i>&nbsp;Philadelphia: Lea &amp; Febiger, 1918; Bartleby.com, 2000.&nbsp;<a href="">www.bartleby.com/107/</a>&nbsp;[Accessed 15 Nov. 2018].&nbsp;</div></div>'

line2 = '''<div><i>CVS</i></div><div>1. Cardiovascular conditioning &amp; improves postural hypotension<br></div><div><b><span style="font-weight: 400;">2. Improves ventilation</span></b><br></div><div><b><span style="font-weight: 400;"><br></span></b></div><div><b><span style="font-weight: 400;"><i>BONES</i></span></b></div><div>3. Promote &amp; maintain bone density, prevent osteoporosis<b><span style="font-weight: 400;"><br></span></b></div><div><br></div><div><i>MUSCLES &amp; JOINTS</i></div>4. Safe reintroduction of the patient to vertical position<div><div>5. Facilitate early weight bearing</div><div><b><span style="font-weight: 400;">6. Prevent contractures</span></b><br></div><div><b><span style="font-weight: 400;"><br></span></b></div><div><b><span style="font-weight: 400;"><i>SKIN</i></span></b></div><div>7. Decreases prolonged bed rest &amp; its complications</div></div><div><br></div><div><i>PSYCHOLOGY</i></div><div>8. Improves psychological outlook &amp; motivation</div>'''

line3 = '''ORIGIN<div>1. Branch of the posterior cord of the brachial plexus -&nbsp;C5, C6.</div><div><br></div><div>COURSE</div>2. Passes out of the axilla, through the quadrangular space with posterior circumflex humeral vessels, to the upper arm where it's in contact with surgical neck of the humerus.&nbsp;</div><div><br></div><div>BRANCHES</div><div><i><font color="#ff086c">3. Sensory supply to small 'regimental patch' over shoulder.</font></i></div><div><i><font color="#ff086c">4. Anterior - supplies the deltoid.&nbsp;</font></i></div><div><i><font color="#ff086c">5. Posterior - supplies teres minor, becomes upper lateral cutaneous nerve of the arm.&nbsp;</font></i></div><i><font color="#ff086c"><img src="paste-6103148528016.jpg"></font></i></div><div><div><b style="font-weight: bold; ">Image:&nbsp;</b>Gray, Henry.&nbsp;<i>Anatomy of the Human Body.</i>&nbsp;Philadelphia: Lea &amp; Febiger, 1918; Bartleby.com, 2000.&nbsp;<a href="https://www.bartleby.com/107/">www.bartleby.com/107/</a>&nbsp;[Accessed 16 Nov. 2018].</div></div>'''
```

You will notice that in `line1` there is no `<div>` tag at all at the beginning, whereas `line2` starts with a  tag but point `4` within is not enclosed in such a tag. `line3` has multiple strings not enclosed in `<div>` tags.

I wrote the following to correct the first line (`line1`):

```
# 1. First, find all lines enclosed in <div> tags
temp_soup = BeautifulSoup(html.unescape(line), "html.parser")
soup = BeautifulSoup("", "html.parser")
for tag in temp_soup.find_all('div'): 
    tag.extract()
    soup.append(tag)

# 2. Then, ensure that the first line starts with the <div> tag, else isolate the first sentence and enclose it between <div> tags
new_div = soup.new_tag("div")
new_div.string = str(temp_soup)
soup.insert(0, new_div)

print(soup)
```

However, the above code does not fix the second line. Moreover, it cannot correct lines with multiple strings not enclosed in `<div>` tags.

Could someone suggest an algorithm to clean up all 3 lines? I've tried `BeautifulSoup.prettify()` and `lxml clean_html()` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried BeautifulSoup.prettify() and lxml clean_html() to no avail.

These generally just make sure that the html is valid, so even if you consider it poorly written, they are unlikely to correct anything unless it makes the html invalid.

---

It's probably not most elegant solution, but I think this will do what you're wanting to:

```py
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

## just a function I use often to reduce whitespace ##
def miniStr(obj, lineSep=' ', wordSep=' '):
    return lineSep.join(wordSep.join(
        w for w in l.split() if w) for l in str(obj).splitlines() if l.strip())


## the solution ##
def containStrings(inpObj, asHtmlStr=True, tCont='div'): 
    ### initiate [main] container - "fixed" html will be added to this ###
    cDiv = BeautifulSoup('<div></div>', "html.parser").div 

    ### format inputs ###
    tCont = str(tCont) if str(tCont).isalpha() else 'div' # can only contain letters
    if not isinstance(inpObj, type(cDiv)): 
        # parses html strings twice [first time to correct errors - like open tags] 
        inpObj = BeautifulSoup(
            f'<div>{BeautifulSoup(inpObj, "html.parser")}</div>', "html.parser").div
    
    ### loop through input and fill up cDiv ###
    for c in inpObj.children:
        if isinstance(c, str): 
            c = BeautifulSoup(f'<{tCont}>{c}</{tCont}>', "html.parser").find(tCont)
        cDiv.append(BeautifulSoup(c.prettify(), "html.parser").find(c.name))

    return cDiv.prettify()[6:-7] if asHtmlStr else cDiv
```

The input can be a HTML string or a bs4 Tag, and the output can also be either [default output is string - set `asHtmlStr` argument as `False` to get a Tag instead].

Also, the "orphan" strings don't necessarily have to be enclosed in `div` tags - you can specify a different Tag name via the `tCont` argument.

---

For test inputs, I copied your sample lines [into a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFmRf.png) named `linesList` - see some of the HTMLs after and before being processed by the function:

[image: op screencap]

The outputs in the above screenshot were printed with:

```py
# the inputs [before processing]
print('\n\n'.join(f'<!--from line{i+1}-->\n'+'\n'.join(
    [miniStr(c, '') for c in BeautifulSoup(l,'html.parser').children]
) for i, l in enumerate(linesList)))
```

```py
# the outputs [after processing]
print('\n\n'.join(f'<!--from line{i+1}-->\n'+'\n'.join(
    [miniStr(c, '') for c in containStrings(l, False).children]
) for i, l in enumerate(linesList)))
```